# how can I integrate video chat in asp.net application?

Tags: asp.net, node.js, twilio

I need to do a video chat application (an application that enables video chat between android phone and pc). I have used "twilio" to do that. For that I installed node.js and git. The problem is my asp.net application runs on "http://localhost:50219/MedApp_Application/Home.aspx" and video application run on "http://localhost:3000/quickstart/". how can I include video chat to asp.net application.

```
     http://localhost:50219/MedApp_Application/Home.aspx
     http://localhost:3000/quickstart/
```

this is the link for the sample twilio application that I used to built video chat application..https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-js

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The Node.js quickstart application you have there just creates an access token for the users of your application. You can see an [example of creating an access token in ASP.NET here](https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/video-access-token-server-csharp). You can also check out the [documentation for creating access tokens for Video here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/identity?code-sample=code-server-token-generation&code-language=cs&code-sdk-version=5.x).

If you generate the token in your C# application then you won't need to run the Node.js application at all. You can then follow the rest of [the documentation to create your Video application](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/getting-started).